# Hibernate entity containing collection - How to show it in JTable

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, tablemodel

There is a simple entity that contains collection of another `Document` entity.

```
class Client{
    private int id;
    private String name; 
    private String secondName; 
    private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet()<Document>; 
    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to show all clients in `JTable`, but client must appear each time for each document he has, for example if client has 3 documents in set, then he should appear in 3 rows with different documents. I have written my own `TableModel`. Is there a way to retrieve from hibernate such suitable collection (I think list of clients with only one document in set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this two-level view, I'd consider two alternatives:

- `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`, shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), would be an appealing choice.
- Use one `JTable` to display the master rows, and add a `ListSelectionListener` that would update a second table's model to display the detail rows for the selected row in the master table. See [*User Selections*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) for details.

Addendum: In your `TableModel`, you can query the database in your implementation of `getValueAt()`, as suggested in this [example](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/08/17/jtable-and-jpa-pagination/index.html/).